# How can I have sublime show hidden files in macOS?

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, configure

I already have finder showing hidden files by using

```
  defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

However, sublime text will not allow me to open hidden files still.

I'm looking for a programmatic way to accomplish this.  So that I don't have to type a special key combination for each dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Press "Command" + "Shift" + "." (dot) to show hidden files in the Mac OSX file chooser dialog.
You can also modify the `folder_exclude_patterns` setting. The default value for this is `"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS"].`  In your case, you would want to make it `"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".hg", "CVS"]`  You can access user settings by going to `Preferences -> Settings - User`

Comment: that works, but I was hoping there was a way to set this to default in the sublime settings or similar.  That way is temporary, as you have to do it each time you open the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The `defaults write` command you entered only sets `AppleShowAllFiles` to true (or `YES`, they're equivalent) for Finder. To enable showing hidden files in all programs, enter

```
defaults write -g AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

The `-g` flag means "global", setting the `AppleShowAllFiles` attribute to true for all programs.

You'll have to restart Sublime after entering this command.